# regex included a-zA-Z, digit, and some symbol with length limit

Tags: regex

I try to create a regex to match lower and uppercase of `A-Z`, `digits` and `@#$_` symbols with length limit of `4 to 16` for all of string.

***My useless regex:***
`/^([a-zA-Z])|(\d)|(@#\$_){4,16}$/`

I test Online regex generators Like http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php but don't have a good result .

Comment: If you want to match 4-6 characters, why are you using `{2,6}`?

Comment: Try `[a-zA-Z0-9@#$_]{4,16}`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV i'ts don't have exact limit `^ and $` on start and end of regex .

Comment: I rename the question to `SOLVED` for accept answer limit time .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex `/^([a-zA-Z])|(\d)|(@#\$_){4,16}$/` matches for a single letter OR a single digit OR 4 to 16 characters of "@#\$_".

The groups around the alternatives are useless.

One solution would be to make a group around the whole alternation

```
/^([a-zA-Z]|\d|@#\$_){4,16}$/
```

but the better solution would be to add everything to one character class

```
/^[a-zA-Z@#$_\d]{4,16}$/
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?342m3)

you can maybe simplify it further, since `[a-zA-Z\d_]` is the same than `\w`, **when `\w` is not unicode based!**

```
/^[\w@#$]{4,16}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

`\w` includes lowercase and UPPERCASE letters, digits and the `_` character

RegEx Pattern: `^[\w@\#\$]{4,16}$`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/rK1yH2

Answer (score 0):

The expression that you need is this one:

```
( ([a-zA-Z])|(\d)|(@#\$_) ){4,6}
```

The problem that you have in yours is that the last {2,6} are affecting only to the last group of brackets, not to the whole expression. Also make sure that the "/^" and "$/" are mandatory for your case, because the "^" means "not", so I'm not sure why you have it there.

You can also see it graphically here: http://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: The `^` negates a character class, when it is the first character in a character class. But elsewhere outside a class it is an anchor for the start of the string